# open slower than web navigators

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I am currently struggling to scrap the following website : http://mangafox.me and am having issues with open :

the following code works just fine for most sites, but I am having issues with mangafox :

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open('http://mangafow.me', 'User-Agent' => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}")
```

I get very fast reponse from https://google.com and most of the tested sites, but keep getting OpenTimeout exceptions on http://mangafox.me and only get the html page sometimes ( after many tries ).

The navigators however, work just fine and have no issues ( even when emptying the cache ) displaying the website quickly.

I am currently using Ruby 2.4.0 and have tried the code on both an archlinux ( manjaro ) and a debian ( ubuntu in windows 10 ) in 2 different locations ( to ensure that my IP is not the issue ).
I also put a sleep ( 0.5 seconds ) between each open to avoid being blocked by doing too many requests.

I also had the same issue with the `curb` gem

```
require 'curb'
html = Curl.get(link)
```

Since the navigators ( tried firefox and chromium ) work perfectly, should I try to imitate them ( by emulating one for example ) ? Or is there an easier solution ( gem / other way to use open / ... ) ?

Comment: Try versus a known-fast link, like `http://example.com`.

Comment: works just fine. It is only for mangafox that I am having issues

Comment: Have you tried to empty the cache of your browsers before testing? Because this difference may be just the result of the cache. The site may be slow for all user agents and you only see this difference because of the cache in your browsers.

Comment: yes, by using a freshly installed chromium instead of firefox

Comment: It's possible you're being rate limited because you're making too many requests.

Comment: I did think about it and did no requests for a day but it still failed on first try. ( it did however work on 3rd try but no more )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you aren't making it clear how you've determined that your browser is faster than the ruby open-uri.

Regardless, there are a number of possibilities:

1. Your browser is caching the page locally (your recent comment implies this isn't the case, though a freshly installed chromium could conceivably be using a shared cache that open-uri doesn't know about
2. Conceivably there is an upstream cache that is caching based on user-agent, though I don't know of such a thing.
3. The website you are accessing supports a protocol that open-uri does not, such as HTTP/2 or SPDY
4. The website is serving different content/protocols based on user-agent.
5. You are being traffic limited (possibly because of your user-agent or your location - you don't mention whether the ruby and browser are running on the same machine)

One of the first tests (after you are clear about how you are determining "speed" versus a browser) would be to try using the same user-agent as your browser, and possibly also having the browser use the same user-agent you are using in ruby.

Comment: thanks a lot for the anwser, there are many things I did not check indeed.
I will edit the question with the new information on how I determined the speed.
How do I get the protocols used by the site ? how do I change the user-agent ?

Comment: updated the question with the info you gave me ( thanks )

Comment: Some of those are different questions and should probably be posted as such (after a thorough google search).

You can change the user-agent directly in your source code, where you specify it.  :)

Comment: I already did that but to no avail, possibly because I did not know what to put ( tryed to copy what firefor was sending )

Comment: That would be a good test.  If you set it to the firefox user-agent and it doesn't change anything, then the speed problems probably aren't user-agent based.

Comment: what test can I do to know what is the problem ?

Comment: You still haven't explained all the issues.  How much time does it take, which file are you getting, how does it work with firefox, etc...

Comment: in the end it got solved by an other update of mangafox so I am a bit confused

Comment: Then it sounds like it was an issue on their end, possibly related to user-agent or what protocol they use.

Comment: without being sure, it does seem like the reason it had issues